# How to read serial port output in Python using pySerial?

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

A device is connected to my PC and I need to write a command via COM Port and get the output. Here is my code

```
from time import sleep
import serial

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.port = 'COM20'

ser.open()
ser.write("system\r")
result = ser.read(100)
print result

ser.close()
```

This is working perfectly. However, different commands return different strings. so I need to read it **without mentioning** no of bytes in `ser.read(100)`.

How can I achieve that? Appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read one byte at the time in a while loop and break when you find the sequence you are looking for, i.e. the data between your protocols start and end control bytes.